# exit 255 when copy with rysnc on linux

Tags: linux, rsync, google-drive

I would like to copy some files from my remote to google drive using rsync. On the terminal I do

```
nohup rsync  /mylocal/mydir/subdir/.  mydrive:folder/data/mydir/subdir &
```

but it exits giving  `Exit 255`.  Where do I do wrong? Thanks

Comment: possibly an underlying ssh error; can you add some `-vvv`'s to the rsync and see if anything drops out?

Comment: JeffSchaller is probably right, but the nohup.out file already created should be consulted just in case it's already explaining what went wrong.  Also, you'll need to look at nohup.out to see the output from the -vvv, unless you redirect stdout and stderr to a file explicitly (in which case it's that file you need to check.)

Comment: thank you both for the comments. Actually, i have tried adding -vvv as well. nohup.out files makes a long list of "Failed to copy: failed to open source object: open file x'" However i am able to copy these files using rclone copy. But I want to use rsync because i have large datasets.

Comment: Should the source path really start with `/`? Should the destination really be relative to your target user's home directory? Shouldn't there be some flags in there too, or aren't you expecting a full directory copy with `--recurse` (`-r`)? Regardless all of this you should definitely be using at least `--times` (`-t`) if not `--archive` (`-a`)

Comment: Try the command without `nohup` and the trailing `&`. Fix those errors and _then_ run it under `nohup`