# Why does running rsync using nohup consume all of a system’s memory?

Tags: ssh, rsync, memory, nohup

Through both testing and plenty of examples on various stack exchanges, its clear that running `rsync` using `nohup` causes memory exhaustion, while the same `rsync` job running via `screen` or an active SSH session does not cause memory exhaustion.

Can anyone explain why this is? Also, is there a way to achieve the same functionality as `nohup` without `screen`?

Comment: Can you cite any examples where you've seen examples of running rsync through nohup causing memory exhaustion, please? I've not seen this myself

Comment: What's *"consume all of a system’s memory?"* How do you know? `RSS`? `Free (?) RAM` output in `top`/`free`? `Free RAM` is almost a **misnomer**. Check `Available RAM` instead.

Comment: plenty of examples on stack exchange, but no explanations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56930250/rsync-error-received-sigint-sigterm-or-sighup-code-20-at-rsync-c544-send#57088900

Comment: Can you add them to your question, please. (With 800 score I didn't think I'd have needed to remind you.)

Comment: You say you've tested this? Please [edit] your question to describe how to reproduce this. Include the exact commands that you run and the outputs that they produce.

Answer (score 1):

Your discrepancy cannot be explained because there is no evidence that it's true.

Relevant references that [I can find](https://www.google.com/search?q=rsync+nohup+out+of+memory), since you've not provided any for your claim:

- [Is rsync really a culprit for causing low memory on our VM?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/727183/100397) - misunderstanding the positive benefits of using "spare" memory for cache
- [nohup parallel and rsync out of memory error](https://askubuntu.com/q/874093/473234) - maybe too many parallel rsync instances simply exhausted available memory? Not enough information to ascertain
- [exit 255 when copy with rysnc on linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503893/100397) - not enough information for any diagnosis